# Weekday Function in SharePoint Calculated Field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a calculated column that is returning a date and timestamp based on other fields in my SharePoint list. So the return for this column called 'final_closed' = 2/26/2021 15:41.

I have another calculated column that I want to return the week ending date (previous Friday) based on the 'final_closed' column. So my function looks like this for 'pr_we' => =If(final_closed ="","",final_closed+6-Weekday(final_closed)).

Here is my issue with the weekday function, it works on most my records in SharePoint, but for some it function is returning '256' and not the actual date.
Is there something I can add to my Weekday function to keep from returning '256' and actually return the previous Friday's date?

Comment: When you get '256' returned', what is the value for [final_closed]? Is it a valid Date?

Comment: I updated the formula.. and now it seems to have fixed itself!!